# Magento 2 how to get data from database?

Tags: magento2, attributes, database

I added an attribute to customer segment, admin can use that attribute to upload image and the database `magento_customersegment_segment` stored the image path in a newly added column `logo`. But how to get back the image path from database and show the image to users?